# Predicate on optional value in swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nspredicate

I am try to predicate on the optional value and it always crash the application with following error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key q_id.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Although there is variable define in the model but it is define like this

```
var q_id : Int!
```

If i convert this variable in unwrap it workings fine

```
var q_id = Int()
```

So is there any other way for predicate on optional value?

```
let Qid = dictData.objectForKey("q_id") as? String
let fQuesID : Int  = Int(Qid!)!;

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.q_id  ==  %i",fQuesID)
let arrObj : NSArray =  arrData.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate) ;
            //arrData.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }
if(arrObj.count > 0)
{
   let objPostModel : ViewPostModel = arrObj.firstObject as! ViewPostModel;
   objPostModel.isPollExpired = 1;  // 1 Means Poll Expired!
   self.tblViewPost?.reloadData();
}
```

It is only happened in primitive optional types variable (int,float,etc ... )

***Update:***
If you make primitive type unoptional then it is working fine

Comment: _So is there any other way for predicate on optional value?_ depends on what you really want to do. Can you show me a pseudo code describing what you want to do if `q_id` is accessible?

Comment: I using this for updating the question with it's respective answer...

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @OOPer code posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `dictData` is an `NSDictionary` containing `String` value for key "q_id",
  `arrData` is an `NSArray` which contains only `ViewPostModel`.
And in the class `ViewPostModel`, `q_id` is a property of type `Int?`.

With all those given, you can write your code in some more Swifty way:

```
    if let
        qId = dictData["q_id"] as? String,
        fQuesID = Int(qId)
    {
        let arrObj = (arrData as! [ViewPostModel]).filter{$0.q_id == fQuesID}
        if let objPostModel = arrObj.first {
            objPostModel.isPollExpired = 1  // 1 Means Poll Expired!
            self.tblViewPost?.reloadData()
        }
    } else {
        print("invalid q_id in dictData")
    }
```

(With declaring your `arrData` as `[ViewPostModel]`, you will have no need to use dangerous `as!` operator. You can make some other parts more Swifty.)

Generally, if you are using `NSPredicate` only to filter an array, better use Swift `filter` method and closure.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.. Let me check this logic